# Where to best store shapes and slides to be used in Office JS Task Pane Addin

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I have an Office JS Task Pane Addin with some different features. For some features I need to store custom shapes that I want the user to be able to insert on slides. I also need to do the similar for complete slides.

For the time being I have a presentation with the relevant shapes and slides arranged to be downloaded and stored locally. But I'm thinking I would rather arrange it so I have a central location where this is stored. When the number of users are growing I have however some concerns regarding response time. What would be the bast arrangement for storing the slides and shapes to be used in the Addin (in a way that avoids response time issues)? On Azure where the have deployed to the Addin itself to?

Appreciate any guidance on this!

Comment: Please clarify some things; By "storing slides" do you mean storing a PPT document with the slides on it? What exactly is your current "stored locally" solution? An add-in cannot access the local hard drive of a computer.

Comment: Yes. Storing a pptx file that keeps both complete slides and custom shapes for direct re-use. The current solution is that the user keeps this "library" pptx file locally and specifies for the Add-in where this is located. When triggering the functions in question from the add-in the slide or shape will be inserted (copied from the "library" pptx file and pasted into the current presentation the user is working on). But obviously this is not the solution I want longer term. I want a central storage location for the file that I can upgrade continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you keep the "library" presentation on a shared OneDrive or SharePoint folder that all users have read permission to. Your add-in can use Microsoft Graph to fetch the presentation. Then your add-in converts it to base64 which you can pass to the `Presentation.insertSlidesFromBase64()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rick! Do you know if a solution with SharePoint / OneDrive would potentially have any response time issues if there are many users trying to access the same content at the same time?

Comment: I *think* that if the traffic to a particular machine in one of the Azure data centers (which is where OneDrive and SharePoint Online are hosted) rises above a certain level, Azure automatically creates load-balanced duplicates of the server, so response time stays high. But I don't know much about how companies with a M365 subscription setup and pay for the subscription. Maybe there's a limit to how much expansion you'll get depending on the how much you're willing to pay.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I had something similar in mind myself but great to have it confirmed before moving forward.